# Передача COMPILE_DEFINITIONS в cmake

Tags: cmake

Как правильно передать `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` cmake параметром через терминал?
Я пытался передавать `-DCOMPILE_DEFINITION(S)="MyOption1"` , `-DCOMPILE_DEFINITION_LIST="MyOption1 MyOption2"`, `-DMyOption1=ON` - эти параметры не передаются.

Но если написать в `CMakeLists.txt` строку `ADD_DEFINITIONS(-MyOption1 -MyOption2)` - они воспринимаются.

Как правильно передать эти параметры через терминал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в неверном задании DEFINITION'ов

```
-DCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS_LIST:STRING="MyOption1;MyOption2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Если писать так:

```
cmake CMakeFiles.txt -Dtest=ON
```

то работать не будет. Нужно так:

```
cmake -Dtest=ON CMakeFiles.txt
```

Comment: Я писал просто cmake -Dtest=ON. Помимо нужного мне параметра, там было куча других, и cmake их понимал

Comment: А нужный параметр случайно не содержит символ `=` или случайно не записан так `-D test=on` или так `"-D test=on"`?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. В командной строке передаются управляющие команды для CMake. Всё остальное нужно прописывать в самом файле. К примеру. `-D` создаёт запись в файле кэш CMake'а.
Если Вам нужно добавлять какие-то дефиниции, в зависимости от параметров переданных в команде cmake, то делайте так:

```
if(MyOption1)
    add_definition(-MyOption1)
endif()
```

А потом вызывайте `cmake -DMyOption1=ON`